# How to save file shared preferences value to firebase and retrieve it

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, synchronization, sharedpreferences

I am doing a simple game app
In which the total score of two simple game is stored in file shared preferences

How shal I sync the score with firebase
And retrieve the score in total score activity

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a model class with User with properties name and email . create setters and getters and store the model object to firebase as below.

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

String userId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
User user = new User("username", "email");

// pushing user to 'users' node using the userId
mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(user);

Retreive the data in other class using the below code
*******************************************************

mDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

        Log.d(TAG, "User name: " + user.getName() + ", email " + user.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey
My total score is stored in file shared preference 
I need to push it to firebase real-time data base
How could I do that

Comment: Hey 
My issue is 
How to push my score value which is stored in file shared preferences
To firebase real-time data base